# Imprimir resultado de un objeto DOM PHP

Tags: php, dom, curl

Hola estoy tratando imprimir resultado de un objeto DOM

```
$dom_os = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$dom_os->load(curl_exec($ch1));



foreach ($dom_os->find('input[type="checkbox"]') as $element) {

    $resultado=$element->value;
    echo $resultado;
}
```

Eso me arroja el siguiente resultado

66563074
66562474
66559985
66562837
27064153

PERO lo que yo necesito es imprimirlo en la siguiente estructura

asignar=&lote=123&orden=&seleccion[]=**66563074,66562474,66559985,66562837,27064153**&tiporden=0&usuario=0

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar lo que estás recibiendo mediante un `var_dump($dom_os);`? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que guardar tus resultados de tu `foreach`  y después imprimirlos separados por coma.

Me refiero a esta parte del código:

```
foreach ($dom_os->find('input[type="checkbox"]') as $element) {

    $resultado=$element->value;
    echo $resultado;
}
```

En lugar de hacer lo anterior, tendrías que hacer esto:

```
$elementos = array();
foreach ($dom_os->find('input[type="checkbox"]') as $element) {

    $resultado=$element->value;
    $elementos[] = $resultado;
}
```

1. Inicializamos un `array` llamado `$elementos` al cual le vamos a ir guardando el valor resultante en cada vuelta de tu `foreach`
2. Este array `$elementos` lo vamos a utilizar para imprimirlos separados por comas.

Utilizaremos una función de php llamada `implode`. Esta funcióno une elementos de un array en un string separados por un delimitador. Lee más acerca de esto [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php)

Entonces, supongamos que los valores guardados en `$elementos` fueron estos:

```
$elementos = array("66563074", "66562474", "66559985", "66562837", "27064153");
```

Y si aplicamos la función de implode sería algo así:

```
echo implode(",", $elementos);
```

Al primer parámetro de `implode` se le llama el delimitador o "glue". Nosotros elegimos el delimitador coma "," pero realmente puede ser cualquier delimitador el cual generá una separación de cada elemento de tu array bajo este delimitador. El resultado sería:

```
66563074,66562474,66559985,66562837,27064153
```

Para que usemos lo anterior, vamos a guardarlo en una variable llamada `$resultado` y la usaremos concatenándola en tu otro string:

```
$resultado = implode(",", $elementos);
```

Tu código final implementando las sugerencias anteriores quedaría así:

```
$dom_os = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$dom_os->load(curl_exec($ch1));



foreach ($dom_os->find('input[type="checkbox"]') as $element) {

    $resultado=$element->value;
    $elementos[] = $resultado;
}

$resultado = implode(",", $elementos);
$string_final = "asignar=&lote=123&orden=&seleccion[]=".($resultado)."&tiporden=0&usuario=0";
```

El valor de `$string_final` debería de ser:

> asignar=&lote=123&orden=&seleccion[]=66563074,66562474,66559985,66562837,27064153&tiporden=0&usuario=0

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo lo que necesitaba

Comment: De nada, enrique, si la respuesta te ha ayudado, te invito a ayudar a la comunidad a saber que esta respuesta fue tu respuesta aceptada, para que otros que tengan la misma duda que tú puedan encontrar la solución más rápido. Saludos.